# grouping and ordering conversation messages with users

Tags: mysql, sql

This title is awful, but can't think of a better one. This is twitter specific, but can apply to any similar application where you have private conversations.

I want to display all direct messages a user might have. All messages from/to a specific user should be grouped together.

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b604dd/14) example.

In this example, I received messages from two users, and replied to one (type of in/out). The first query is simply ordering by date descending. The order is 3 2 1, but what I really want is 3 1 2 because 3 it's the latest, and 1 is related to 3.

The second query gets the correct order, but using GROUP_CONCAT. This makes for very messy query, and I would rather have one message in each row so I don't have to split them in PHP.

The third query was added because I'm not yet sure if I want to order each conversation ASC or DESC. This one does the GROUP_CONCAT ASC correctly, but because the message from user2 is newer than the first message from user1, the two rows are reversed.

Hope this makes sense. The two orders I would like to achieve are 3 1 2 and 1 3 2, each message as its own row, and two different queries. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT *
FROM   test
ORDER BY "user", date DESC;
```

EDIT:

You want to order *users* by the time of their most recent message.  That requires something like a `join`:

```
select t.*
from test t join
     (select user, max(date) as maxdate
      from test
      group by user
     ) tu
     on t.user = tu.user
order by tu.maxdate desc, user, date desc;
```

Comment: No, that will order users in alphabetical order. I still want the order from message to message to be date desc, just all from the same user put together if there are more messages from that user.

Comment: @PatrickSt.Onge . . . That's why I answered and asked.  Now I think I understand what you want much better.